# Chart.js Annotations plugin - annotation not appearing in Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, chart.js2

The chart.js **annotations plugin** is not behaving as expected in my wordpress template. The chart renders fine but the annotations just don't appear. I've tried putting the annotations config in "plugins" and also right under options to no avail. Finally I tried copy-pasting the codepen example right into my own code and got the same result - no annotations. Now I'm totally confused :p

I have duplicated [this code pen example](https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/yaGGGW?editors=1000) exactly (I think) on my staging server but, while the annotation (a line) appears in code pen, it does not appear on my site. I think (?) I have the same versions of everything installed and I have enqueued the annotations plugin to list chart.js as a dependency. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

From my plugin file (fws_wpt_pdf.php):

```
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chart_js', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js", array('jquery'), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chart_annotation_js', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/master/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js', array('chart_js'), false, true );
```

From my javascript file (fws_pdf.js):

```
var canvas = $(selector)[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = {
    labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,191,255,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(0,191,255,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(100,149,237,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(100,149,237,1)",
            data: [60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20],
            borderColor: 'grey',
            borderWidth: 1,        
        }
    ]};

    var options = {
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
          ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },        
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },        
      }]
    },      
      annotation: {
        annotations: [{
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: '26',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 3
        }],
        drawTime: "afterDraw" // (default)
    }
  };

// Chart declaration:
var multiLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

From my template file (entry-content-wpt-test-get-results.php):

```
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
        <canvas id="test_chart" data-label="<?php echo $result->getTitle() ?>" data-x_value="<?php echo $scales[1]->getValue(); ?>" data-y_value="<?php echo $scales[0]->getValue(); ?>" data-x_max_value="<?php echo $scales[1]->getMaximum(); ?>" data-y_max_value="<?php echo $scales[0]->getMaximum(); ?>"></canvas>
    </div>
```

This is probably just a silly mistake on my part. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! I'm developing the template for an older Wordpress theme and it forced usage of jQuery 1.8 (!). when I stopped it from doing that and loaded the up-to-date jQuery (3.4.1), annotations started working again **whew!** Now I have to track down all the deprecated things in the theme with jQuery migrate (Grrrrr)